# Need help understanding a NullPointerException

Tags: java, class

This line of code gave me an error.

```
Scanner sce = new Scanner(new File("employees.txt"));

while(sce.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] obj = sce.nextLine().split(", ");
    Employee e = new Employee(obj);
    department d = new department(e); //Here is where the error pops up (Main.java:29)
    ...
}
```

I'm scanning the text file and splitting the different fields into a string array then declaring an object from the `Employee` class. I then declare an object from the `department` class using the object from the `Employee` class and I run into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ssst.edu.ba.department.<init>(department.java:19)
    at ssst.edu.ba.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

My `department` Class:

```
package ssst.edu.ba;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class department {
    private ArrayList<Employee> Marketing;
    private ArrayList<Employee> Production;
    private String department;

    public department() {
    }

    public department(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public department(Employee employee) {
        if(employee.getDepartment() == "Marketing") Marketing.add(employee);
        else Production.add(employee); //This is the other location (department.java:19)
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public ArrayList<Employee> getMarketing() {
        return Marketing;
    }

    public ArrayList<Employee> getProduction() {
        return Production;
    }
}
```

The file *employees.txt* is as follows:

> ```
> Ginny, Gullatt, Marketing, 1000
> Tiara, Curd, Production, 1200
> amie, Poorman, Marketing, 900
> Jammie, Hasson, Marketing, 800
> Lionel, Hailey, Marketing, 500
> Genevive, Mckell, Production, 2000
> Esteban, Slaubaugh, Marketing, 1300
> Elden, Harte, Production, 1340
> Tasia, Rodrigue, Marketing, 1200
> Nathanial, Dentler, Production, 1700
> Valda, Nicoletti, Marketing, 600
> Kary, Wilkerson, Production, 600
> Coletta, Akey, Marketing, 800
> Wilmer, Jack, Production, 600
> Loreta, Agnew, Marketing, 700
> Suzy, Cleveland, Production, 1450
> Pasty, Laprade, Marketing, 1300
> Candie, Mehaffey, Production, 1800
> Glady, Landman, Marketing, 1900
> Tierra, Mckeown, Production, 2200
> ```

Comment: You never initialize `Production` or `Marketing` eg `Marketing = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I would say you just forgot to instantiate your lists

```
private ArrayList<Employee> marketing;
```

And in the constructor

```
marketing = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

An other point, variable names should start with lowercase. Uppercase are for classname.

Comment: since we have 3 constructors, that is not the best solution, but correct (if extended to the other constructors)

Answer (score 0):

The arraylist Production is uninitialized as well as Marketing. In the constructor you should initialize all the class variables. Also, compare Strings with .equals()

```
public department(Employee employee) { 
    Marketing = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Production = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    if("Marketing".equals(employee.getDepartment())) Marketing.add(employee);
    else Production.add(employee); 
}
```

EDIT: Doing "Marketing".equals() prevents a null pointer exception as Christopher pointed out

Comment: In most cases, it's even better to reverse that string comparison logic. `"Marketing".equals(employee.getDepartment());`, though sometimes that can hide a legitimate error. This prevents a NullPointerException if `getDepartment` returns null.  If it's required that `department` is never null, you shouldn't allow it to be null.

Comment: Then we disagree. I find that is easier to read and is certainly less verbose than `employee.getDepartment() != null && employee.getDepartment().equals("Marketing")`. It is a perfectly legitimate use-case, and the logic is identical.